# Error due to wsimport on JDK7 and JAVAC support JDK6 - compatibility issue

Tags: java, ant, jax-ws, java-7, java-6

I am using `ANT 1.6 /JAX-WS 2.0/Weblogic 11g` in my project. I got requirement where our build machine is on `JDK7` but our deployment machine (include weblogic) is on `JDK6`. Now I am getting an error while creating war file.

Steps -  Before creating war file in `build.xml` file: 
1) I am calling wsimport with `JDK7` as default java home is `JDK7` (because build machine is now on `JDK7`) where I am setting `-Xnocompile` so the source code is not compiled with default `JDK7`. 
2) During execution of javac where I have specified property `[source ="6" target="6" fork="false"|"true"` (both combination of fork one at a time)] to make build compatible with `JDK6`. However, I am getting error while reading the code generated by wsimport.

The issue is what I understood so far - we are doing wsimport from `JDK7` and compile the code with setting the property as `JDK6`. So `JDK7`'s generated java files are not supported during `javac` execution.

I am getting similar error like below - FYI, `ADMIN.java` file generated by `wsimport` command in my `build.xml` file.

```
 C:\MyProject\src\com\company\abc\xyz\delivery\ws\ADMIN.java:46: cannot find symbol 
    [javac] symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
    [javac] location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
    [javac]         super(__getWsdlLocation(), ADMIN_QNAME, features);<br>
    [javac]
```

Comment: You can't do that, compiling using higher version and running using lower version. Use the same version for compilation and runtime. Reverse is mostly possible, compile in lower version and running in higher version.

Comment: During compilation I am putting up the value inside javac tag like source="1.6" target="1.6" which make code compiled on 1.6 only, although java_home is jdk7/jdk8 etc. And I want to run the code on 1.6 only. Issue is Java_home is JDK7 which import files are not able to compiled. Now file generated by wsimport using JDK7 but during compilation (javac) I can control which java version should used from source and target - getting error during compilation.

Comment: If you particular about run time version, why not use the same to compile, what is stopping you?

Comment: the build machine is on JDK7 but where we deploying our application that environment is on JDK6.

Comment: It is better to sync the version if you need to proceed, that is only i can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to fix the above issue anyway apart from change the Java_home option of our build machine and point to JDK6 or your running java version.